# IOS 5 - webview not displaying html rendered from reportviewer contro(.NET)

Tags: iphone, .net, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am requesting aspx page which is using reportviewer control  and returning html.

Problem faced:
IOS 5 : It fails to render this html on first attempt. But when you close the app and log in again, Report is  getting rendered properly after a long time.
IOS-4 : It works fine there, that is, html is  getting rendered properly in first attempt on webview.

Research:
1)On browsers firebug, I saw that aspx url itself making multiple internal requests, that is, 1 main aspx is calling internally urls such as
a)http://..../..../Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=.....
b)about blank
2)When I compare IOS-4 and IOS-5 request logs, I saw there is requests mismatch. In IOS-4, there were 6 requests in total where as in IOS-5 there were 5 requests. In some of the request,webview didfinishload delgate not getting fired.
3)I tried with google.com, its getting rendered properly on both IOS.
4)I pasted the url on safari browser of iphone,the report is getting displayed properly.

I am using this:
[wvDisplayHTMLURL loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLHTML]]];
where strURLHTML contains aspx url and wvDisplayHTMLURL is webview.

Is the problem is from iphone side or server side(Ajax/Javascript)?
Any one has solution for this? Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple seems to have made some changes in the WebView control for iOS 5.

I think your best option would be to identify and solve this issue from server side.